# JavaScript with Ajax call to the WordPress API

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm making a Wordpress plugin named "customposttype" that makes a custom post type with 3 custom fields. The plugin also must do an Ajax call to the WordPress API and gets all the data from those posts in JSON format, to show them in a specific template called "shoplist.php".

My CPT is called "tienda", it has this url for the REST API: ...wp-json/wp/v2/tiendas.

I'm sure that I have several errors because it's my first time using an API and I'm very bad at Javascript.

I'm stuck just right here, I don't know how to continue developing it.

JS shows "Hello world!" at the console, but nothing else.

**PHP**

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_shop_data", "get_shop_data");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_shop_data", "get_shop_data");
    
function get_shop_data() {
 
    $api_url = "https://pezquefuma.es/wp-json/wp/v2/tiendas";
    $request = wp_remote_get($api_url);
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
    $output = json_encode($body, true);
    echo $output;

    die();
}
    
    function my_enqueue() {
    if ( get_page_template_slug() == 'shoplist.php' ) {
    
     wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url('customposttype/js/filename.js'), array('jquery') );
      wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object', array( 
          'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
          'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my-nonce')
          ) 
      );
    }
 }
     
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

**JS**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
console.log("Hello world!");

jQuery.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "JSON",
    url : my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
    data : {
        action: "get_shop_data",
    },

    error: function(response, error) {
        console.log("wrong");
    },

    success : function(response) {
        if(response.type === "success") {
            console.log("Success");
        }
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Did you check the response data on success? please add console.log(response)

Comment: Check Network tab of your browser’s devtools and see what happened with the request.

Comment: try a POST request

Comment: @RomanGavrilov I've added the console.log(response) line     success : function(response) {
        if(response.type === "success") {
            console.log(response);
        }  --> nothing happens

Comment: please add console.log(response) to above of if condition
success : function(response) {
       console.log(response);
        if(response.type === "success") {
            console.log("Success");
        }
    }

Comment: then check the response

Comment: @RomanGavrilov Yes, now I can see the response at the console, and it's the same as the one I saw in the request in the browser's devtools. I still don't know why the "wrong" or "success" messages never appear, but it doesn't matter now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @James, that was a key. The network tool tab whos the JSON at the response tab.

Comment: @JorgeGL Glad we could troubleshoot this - I have taken that comment and turned it into an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to check response data.
one is to use browser's network devtool and another is to use console.log

```
 success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
  }
```